# How to clone outputs instead of "unify" in Kubuntu 16.04?

Tags: kubuntu, external-monitor, plasma-5

In Kubuntu 16.04 (with Plasma 5.8) I cannot clone my laptop monitor to an external display. There is a setting "Unify outputs" which will set both monitors to the same resolution, but they are still arranged side by side, and not cloned.

I can clone the output from the command line using something like `xrandr --output VGA1 --same-as LVDS1` but it would be nice to be able to do it also from the GUI, the way it used to be possible before 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with HDMI monitors, just not with VGA.